# Liste von Schachmetaphern in der deutschen Sprache: Welche fehlen noch?

Tags: idiom, metaphor

Gibt es eine vollständige Liste von Schachmetaphern und durch Schach inspirierte Redewendungen in der deutshen Sprache? Die ausführlichste Liste, die ich gefunden habe, steht auf der Website des [Schachklubs Dornbin](http://www.skdornbirn.at/skip5shop.aspx?ogr=0&gr=27&art=0&param=dynMenu&wert=0):

- Schach dem/der [+ Dativ];
- x in Schach halten;
- jemanden wie eine Schachfigur herumschieben;
- schachmatt (Adjektiv: am Boden, außer Gefecht) & jemanden schachmatt setzen;
- ein [kluger / politischer / ...] Schachzug;
- Schachbrettmuster;
- eine Patt-Situation;
- am Zug (sein) [könnte auch aus einem anderen rundenbasierten Brettspiel kommen; siehe O. R. Mapper's Bemerkung unten];
- in Zugzwang (sein / geraten);
- Bauernopfer;
- Rochade (z.B. Personalrochade); rochieren (z.B. im Fußball: "Auffallend ist, wie stark die Offensivspieler rochieren ...");
- Rösselsprung ("Er [...] würde Rösselsprünge durch die Diskurse vollführen, statt klar zu deduzieren.")
- Hängepartie (cf. neulich Brexit);
- getürkt (cf. Schachtürke).

Was ich in dieser Liste nicht gefunden habe, ist "Gambit". (In der englischen Sprache kann [gambit](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gambit) auch figurativ benutzt werden; siehe z.B. "[President Putin's Middle East gambit](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-18574738)".)

Fehlen in der Liste noch andere Metaphern und Redewendungen?

Comment: _Gambit_ fehlt nicht in der Liste; man benutzt es einfach nicht außerhalb des Schachs.

Comment: Ist *am Zug (sein)* wirklich eine Schachmetapher? Die Ausdrucksweise trifft doch auf so ziemlich jedes rundenbasierte Brettspiel, bei dem man Figuren *zieht*, zu.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Es stimmt, dass "Zug" auch auf andere Brettspiele zutrifft. Die Frage ist aber, welches Brettspiel populär genug wahr, um die allgemeine Sprache zu beinflussen.

Comment: Wie soll man diese Frage beantworten können, ohne selbst eine vollständige Liste zu haben? Gut - ich habe ein Element das nicht auf der Liste ist, das sollte reichen, aber wenn ich das nicht hätte? Und woher soll ich wissen, dass nicht in einer antiken Schublade eine vollständige Liste liegt?

Comment: Dies ist eigentlich eine gute Frage, muss aber überarbeitet werden. Es ist unmöglich eine vollständige Liste zu erkennen!

Comment: Mir fehlt noch "etwas _en passant_ erledigen".

Comment: @Ingmar: Sicher, dass *en passant* schachspezifisch ist und sich die deutsche Redewendung nicht einfach aus der französischen Bedeutung ergeben hat?

Comment: Ich weiß, dass _ich_ die Phrase in dieser Form mit dem Brettspiel assoziiere.

Comment: @Ingmar: Nun gut, da ich zwar Französisch, jedoch kein Schach kann, ist es nicht weiter verwunderlich, dass ich da eine andere Assoziation habe ;)

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe: Mag sein, dass Schach so populär war/ist. Vielleicht aber auch etwas anderes, wie *Mensch ärgere dich nicht*. Andererseits kann es auch genauso gut sein, dass es eben weder einen konkreten Bezug zu Schach noch zu irgendeinem anderen Brettspiel gibt, sondern nur auf rundenbasierte Brettspiele generell (in der Summe sind diese sicherlich noch populärer als Schach allein). Beispielsweise beziehen sich ja auch Metaphern wie "die Karten werden neu gemischt" eher nicht auf ein konkretes Kartenspiel, sondern auf Kartenspiele im Allgemeinen.

Comment: @Ludi: Ich habe die Frage überarbeitet; jetzt wird nicht mehr nach einer vollständigen Liste gefragt.

Comment: @Christophe Strobbe Please notice that the link you provided in your question does not seem to work, at least on August 01.

Comment: @EugeneStr. Sorry. I have fixed the link.

Comment: "Endspiel". Und möglicherweise "Remis" (keine Ahnung inwieweit das auch außerhalb des Schachspiels verwendet wird).

Comment: @EikePierstorff Danke für "Endspiel". Das Wort wird u.a. in politischer Berichterstattung benutzt. Siehe z.B. [Endspiel für die Gasprinzessin](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/timoschenko-prozess-in-kiew-endspiel-fuer-die-gasprinzessin-a-784356.html). Allerdings bedeutet "Endspiel" oft "das letzte Spiel (in einem Turnier)", und in manchen Schlagzeilen mutet mir das Wort zweideutig an, z.B. [Endspiel geht in die Verlängerung](http://www.n-tv.de/politik/Merkel-spielt-Schwarzer-Peter-article15355661.html).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a big-list answer which is typically discouraged on this platform.

Comment: @Jan It only asks for additions to the proposed list, and the list is already fairly complete. So it does definitely not ask for a *big* list.

Answer (score 1):

Es ist offensichtlich nicht so einfach, andere Redewendungen und Metaphern hinzuzufügen. Zu den Vorschlägen in den Kommentaren habe ich Folgendes gefunden:

- *am Zug (sein)* ist nicht notwendigerweise eine Schachmetapher, sondern könnte aus einem anderen Brettspiel stammen. (*Deutsches Wörterbuch von Jacob und Wilhelm Grimm*: "der zug ist an einem" wird nicht speziell auf das Schachspiel bezogen.)
- *[etwas] en passant [erledigen]* kommt nich notwendigerweise aus dem Schachspiel. *DUDEN - Das große Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache in 10 Bänden* erwähnt den französischen Ursprung (und die Bedeutung im Schach).
- *Endspiel*: Siehe z.B. [Endspiel für die Gasprinzessin](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/timoschenko-prozess-in-kiew-endspiel-fuer-die-gasprinzessin-a-784356.html). Allerdings bedeutet "Endspiel" oft "das letzte Spiel (in einem Turnier)", und in manchen Schlagzeilen mutet mir das Wort zweideutig an, z.B. [Endspiel geht in die Verlängerung](http://www.n-tv.de/politik/Merkel-spielt-Schwarzer-Peter-article15355661.html).
- *Remis* (Adjektiv & Substantiv): *DUDEN - Das große Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache in 10 Bänden* erwähnt die Herkunft aus dem Französischen (remis, 2. Partizip von *remettre* = zurückstellen) und die Verwendung im Schach.
- Dass jemand (nur) *Springer am Rand* ist (d.h. keine Rolle von Bedeutung spielen kann) ist offensichtlich keine geläufige Redewendung. (Keine Erwähnung in *DUDEN - Das große Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache in 10 Bänden* oder *Das große Lexikon der sprichwörtliche Redensarten* von Lutz Röhrich.)
- *Kiebitzen* ("bei einem Spiel, z.B. einem Kartenspiel oder Schach, zuschauen und Ratschläge geben") stammt vom gaunersprachlichen "kiewitschen, kiebitschen" (cf. Jiddisch: "koiwesch") (s. *Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen*, hrsg. W. Pfeiffer, 2. Aufl., Akademie Verlag, 1993). Die weitere Herkunft ist laut *KLUGE* unklar (*KLUGE Etymologisches Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache*). Das Substantiv *Kiebitz* (lästiger Zuschauer) wurde dann an den Vogelnamen angeglichen (*KLUGE*). Das Wörterbuch der Brüder Grimm erwähnt das Verb nicht.

Answer (score 1):

Ergänzen könnte man noch:

- *der Kiebitz* / *kiebitzen*. [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiebitz_(Spielbeobachter)) zufolge fand diese Bezeichnung für einen (Spiel-)Beobachter ihren Weg vom Rotwelsch zuerst in die Schachsprache und von dort weiter über die Kartenspiele in die Umgangssprache
- *in Zugzwang geraten* hast Du schon genannt. In der Umgangssprache sind aber anders als im Schach mit der Aktion nicht immer negative Folgen für den Akteur verbunden - der Fokus liegt eher auf dem Druck, überhaupt etwas tun zu müssen.