# Welche Verstärkungswörter sind in der Jugendsprache am populärsten?

Tags: particle, big-list, teen-slang

Ich bin eine Studentin aus Moskau und schreibe eine Diplomarbeit zum Thema *Verstärkung in der Jugendsprache*.

Ich möchte gern wissen, welche Wörter zurzeit verwendet werden, um Verstärkung (mit dem Sinn *sehr* oder *stark)* auszudrücken, und welche davon am populärsten sind?

Comment: Servus und willkommen auf dem Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Du kannst eine [Tour] der Seite nehmen. Mehr darüber, wie sie funktioniert, erfährst du im [Help]. Persönlich halte ich die Frage für zu breitgefächert, weil es sehr viele Verstärkerworte in der Jugendsprache gibt, und deren Popularität viel zu sehr von Region, Schultyp und Geschlecht abhängt.

Comment: 1998 wurde das übrigens schon mal erforscht: https://jannisandroutsopoulos.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/wie-sagt-man-sehr-gut-in-der-jugendsprache.pdf

Comment: 1998 ist schon so Mittelalter... @Iris

Answer (score 6):

Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob ich deine Frage richtig verstehe, aber vielleicht meinst du Wörter wie: **krass, mega, ultra, heftig, abnormal, hammer**,...

Ich kann dir bestätigen, dass diese Wörter häufig benutzt werden, da ich selber noch Jugendlicher bin.

Wie populär die Wörter sind, hängt vermutlich nochmal von der Altersgruppe und sicher auch von der Gegend ab.

Comment: Bestimmt. Aber das beantwortet die Frage auch nur zu ca. einem Drittel, weil 1. die Liste nicht vollständig ist und 2. nichts über deren Popularität gesagt wird.

Comment: Die Frage war, welche Woerter verwendet werden und welche populaer sind. Die genannten Woerter werden verwendet, das weis ich, weil ich selber noch jugendlich bin. Ob es weitere Woerter gibt? Bestimmt, aber ich kenne sie nicht. Die hier genannten sind die meiner Meinung nach populaersten (zumindest in meiner Gegend).

Comment: @Jan Aber es ist ein guter Anfang. _Vollständig_ kann so eine Liste niemals sein, weil sich _immer_ jemand finden wird, in dessen Gegend "super-…" geläufiger ist. Fragen nach _vollständigen_ Listen von irgendwas (z.B. [Schachmetaphern](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/31092/22180)) kann man sowieso nicht endgültig beantworten. Dazu ist viel zu viel Bewegung in der Sprache und was gestern noch "supergeil" war, ist heute vielleicht "endgeil".

Comment: Sind *fett*, *voll*, *sau~*, *schweine~* wieder out?

Comment: fett und voll gibt's noch ;) sau und schwein hab ich noch nie benutzt :o